# @ManytoMany annotation issue org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find physical table `producto`

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with Spring Boot 1.3.1 and its default hibernate version 4.3.11.Final. I'm trying to map a @ManytoMany association, but I get the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]    at
>   ec.com.asertec.ave360.Ave360beApplication.main(Ave360beApplication.java:60)
>   [bin/:na] Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:860)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]   ... 14 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find
>   physical table: `producto`    at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.getLogicalTableName(Configuration.java:3156)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.getLogicalTableName(Configuration.java:3149)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1208)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:794)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:729)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]  ... 22
>   common frames omitted

My entities are:

**PRODUCTO entity:**

```
  @Entity
@Table(name="producto",schema="ave360")
@NamedQuery(name="Producto.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Producto p")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Producto  extends EntidadBase implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_producto", schema = "ave360", sequenceName = "producto_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ID_producto")
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, name = "nombre", length = 250, nullable = false)
    private String nombre;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_nivel_organizacional")
    private NivelOrganizacional nivelOrganizacional;


     @ManyToMany(
                targetEntity=Ramo.class
            )
     @JoinTable(
             name="producto_ramo",
             joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_producto",referencedColumnName="id"),
             inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_ramo",referencedColumnName="id")
     )
    private Set<Ramo> ramos;
```

**RAMO entity:**

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the ramo database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="ramo",schema="ave360")
@NamedQuery(name="Ramo.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM Ramo r")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Ramo extends EntidadBase implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_ramo", schema="ave360", sequenceName = "ramo_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ID_ramo")
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="codigo_super", nullable=false,unique=true)
    private Integer codigoSuper;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=150,unique=true)
    private String nombre;

    @Column(length=450)
    private String descripcion;

    @Column(length=15,unique=true,nullable=false)
    private String siglas;

    @ManyToMany(
            mappedBy = "ramos",
            targetEntity = Producto.class
        )
    private Set<Producto> productos;
```

When I remove the @ManyToMany mapping, it works fine. I have in others entities that have ManytoOne mapping and OneToOne mapping and everything works fine.

I've tried to look for solutions, but I couldn't find it.

Could you look at the code and the logs and help me to see what it's wrong? Maybe I'm misssing something.

Many thanks to all of you.

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find physical table: producto at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.getLogicalTableName(Configuration.java:3156) ----- Are you certain the producto table is in your DB?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also tried with spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update, but not with create.

Comment: Underscore is a reserved char in JPQL. As a shot in the dark, you might try using a different name dor the join table.